# Does MongoDB BI Connector support INSERT/UPDATE operations?

Tags: sql, mongodb, business-intelligence

Does the MongoDB BI connector support INSERT and UPDATE SQL commands?

I want to use the BI connector to INSERT data into MongoDB from an SQL connection.

I've looked through all your documentation but I cannot find any concrete answer.

Is that supported? Thank you.

Comment: Tecnically [it's possible](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/reference/drdl/#aggregation-pipelines). Try to use in `pipeline` `$out` o `$merge` operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MongoDB Connector for BI](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/) currently provides a read-only interface to a MongoDB deployment via the MySQL wire protocol or [ODBC](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/reference/odbc-driver/).

This is intended to be used for querying and reporting on data in MongoDB with BI tools rather than being a full SQL interface for CRUD interaction.

For more details, see [Supported SQL Functions & Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/supported-operations/) in the BI Connector documentation.